# Vue: positioning logo component to have zero margin top

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a simple `vue` component like this:

**Logo.vue**:

```
<template>
    <img id="logo" alt="Vue logo" width="300"
         src="../assets/logo.png">
</template>

<style scoped>
    img  {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-left: 80%;

        width: 300px;

    }

    template  {
        background-color:red;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

</style>
```

I'm using it in the `App.vue` like this:

**App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Logo/>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
 import Logo from './components/Logo.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Logo

  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #36383F;
  color: #DCDDDE;
  height: 1500px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>
```

It gives this result:

[image]

However I would like it to be closer to the top and rightmost edge, like this:

[image]

But putting `margin-top: 0;` didn't do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Well what about position absolute:

```
 img  {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 300px;
    }
```

If you want your logo to stick always on the top right even if you scroll then use `position: fixed`